# Issue with TestFlight Build information : ITC.apps.tf.build.test.info.missing.feedback testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, testflight

I have submitted app to test flight. When I am adding information to that build I am getting an error "Sorry, something went wrong".

> ITC.apps.tf.build.test.info.missing.feedback testflight

Did any one facing this issue?

[image]

Comment: I know it's been a while, but, see my answer below... hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a requirement to fill out the "Test Information". On the left hand side menu, under "APP INFORMATION", you should see "Test Information". Click the link and fill in the form that appears on the right. Then, click save. Return to the "Test Details" page and you should be able to successfully save the test details.

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine now. May be it's issue from apple server.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, got that error when trying to add test information by clicking "Test details" link.
Instead, add a group/users to the test while in "Testers" area. It opens a popup which leads you to give the test information and submit the build to review. That worked for me. 
 [image: Picture of the test page]